# Magic Mirror Google Assistant

Tags: json, magic-mirror

I installed magic mirror, configured google-assistant according to http://wiki.bugsounet.fr/en/MMM-GoogleAssistant/ , but when I try to run it, Magic Mirror starts and an error comes up with error when loading this recipie: MMM-TelegramBot.js. I can also see two logos one of google and the other of alexa. When I call Jarvis the google logo starts blinking but nothing happens after that.